# How to get top5 users by the quantity (2 tables connected with each other)?

Tags: python, django

My models:

```
class Institution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    type = models.CharField(choices=type_of_organization, default=1, max_length=32)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class Donation(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

How can i get top 5 users by the quantity for each Institution?
For example, for Institution_id = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elements = Donation.objects.filter(Institution.id=1).order_by('quantity')[:5]
```

you get the donation objects now for Institution id = 1, when you pass it to the template, you can do:

```
 {% for element in elements %} 
  {{ element.user }}     
 {% endfor %}
```

or you can get the username by

```
 {{ element.user.username }}
```

this should give you the top 5 users that made the best donation for the particular institution that you filtered.

If you want to get the sum of donatıons for each user and calculate who made the best offer,

**First solution to this**

is to change your model:
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
your user should be unique so each time a user made a donation, you should add on the previous quantity. Not another table for it. In views.py change the way you store data. pseudo-code is like this: ( if a user made a donation before:
donation.quantity += newdonation )

**Second solution**

You will do a dictionary to keep track of user and donations.
try this in your views.py:

```
  elements = Donation.objects.filter(Institution.id=1).order_by('quantity')
  donationlist = {} //created an empty dict.
  for element in elements:
   donation = element.quantity
   user = element.user 
   if user not in donationlist:
       donationlist.add(user,donation) #now if the user hasn't made a donation yet it will create new key-pair in our dictionary. 
   else: 
       previousdonation = donationlist[user]
       sum = previousdonation + donation
       donationlist[user] = sum 
       # now we updated the users donation successfully if had another donation before. 

    print(donationlist).
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a problem - i have got 5 user with biggest donations, not the sum of them, for example - User who made 1 donation with quantity of 100 would be higher than 2 donations 60 quantity each.

Comment: It works :) Thanks so much, i should have find out by myself that dictionary is needed, i tried just to make a query for that.